# Converting non-breaking spaces to regular spaces in an encoded Ruby string

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

If a Ruby string contains spaces and non-breaking spaces, and we don't know which encoding was used to represent them, how can you convert all spaces (breaking and non-breaking) in the string to simple breaking spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `string.gsub("\u00A0", " ")`

Comment: I can't test it right now but as far as I know this may not work in ruby versions < 1.9.2. Otherwise, this should do it.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately not. I was previously on Ruby 1.8.7 and just switched to Ruby 1.9.2. I still get: